# How to match all X after Y?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
A1xB2xC3yD4xE5xF6x
```

I want to match (then replace) every `x`, but only the ones after `y`.  Expected matches: `x`, `x`, `x`.
I tried this:

```
(?<=y)x
```

But it doesn't work.  Supposedly it matches `x` preceded by `y`, but only IMMEDIATELY preceded by `y`.

So I tried this:

```
(?<=.*y.*)x
```

But apparently the `*` and even the `+` symbols are not valid and throw an error if used inside that group.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

The solution cannot be "the last 3 `x`'s", because the number of `x`'s after `y` is unknown.

Comment: What is your regex language?

Comment: I was using https://regex101.com/ and forgot to change it to JavaScript.  I just did and it works.  So should I close the question?

Comment: How about finding where the first `y` is, create a substring from that index, and match `x` in that substring?

Comment: In Javascript `/(?<=y[^y]*)x/g` should work

Comment: If you found the solution describe it in your own answer below. If community thinks the solution makes the question off-topic it will be closed. If you think that the question is not worth any effort, then please delete it (closing is not an option for you, but probably you meant deleting).

Comment: lookbehind is not supported in IE, Safari and few other https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moden Javascript regex engine allows lookbehind assertion of variable length so looking at your question this regex should work for you:

```
/(?<=y[^y]*)x/gi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v3kLpa/1)

This regex asserts presence of `y` followed by 0 or more non-`y` characters before matching a `x`.

Comment: “But apparently the `*` and even the `+` symbols are not valid and throw an error if used inside that group” suggests that their engine doesn’t support variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: So JavaScript regex is actually the most advanced?

Comment: @GirkovArpa `.NET` also supports variable length lookbehind.

Comment: This is case insensitive and hence making an assumption that there are no "xXyY" except the special ones, isn't it? I.e. there should not be a X9 or Y9 or similar anywhere. That seems a reasonable assumption, looking at the provided sample input. But do you agree to that assumption being made?

Comment: @Yunnosch: I used `/i` just because OP wrote `X` and `Y` in title but used `x` and `y` in question body.

Comment: Try that with input "A1xB2xC3yD4xE5xF6xX9", result is "A1xB2xC3yD4@E5@F6@@9" (with your replacement "@"). Could be OK, could be undesired. (I do see the accept tick....; discussing possibly missed test input.)

Comment: @anubhava: It’s in the body of the question. When this answer works, their original regex does too. (This is a more efficient version, though.)